# Move data between classes and then iterate through the new class from the html page

Tags: angular, typescript

## The Setup

I have an angular 7 app that gets data from a web api in the form of JSON.  As the app stands now it works but I think I am making too many API calls and I think I can reduce them to 1.

**myClass:**

```js
    export class myclass {
        constructor(tagname: string, value: number, description: string, units: string, quality: string, timestamp: string, lowlimit: number, highlimit: number, asset: string) {
            this.tagname = tagname;
            this.value = value;
            this.description = description;
            this.units = units;
            this.quality = quality;
            this.timestamp = timestamp;
            this.lowlimit = lowlimit;
            this.highlimit = highlimit;
            this.asset = asset;
        }
        tagname: string;
        value: number;
        description: string;
        units: string;
        quality: string;
        timestamp: string;
        lowlimit: number;
        highlimit: number;
        asset: string;
    }
```

**dashboard.component.ts** - within here I have an array of type `myClass`.

```
mylist: myClass[];
```

This is populated from within `ngOnInit` using:

```
this._myService.getcurrentvalues()
      .subscribe
      (
        (data: myClass[]) => this.mylist= data

      );
```

I then call this from the html component using:

```
<mat-card-content *ngFor="let com of myList">
```

This allows me to generate for example a line of text per entry in the list with the following:

```
<p class="tag-description">{{com.description}}</p>
```

## The Goal

I am calling the API about 6 times for the one html component so I thought why dont I just get all the data in 1 API call and then amend it from within the application as this should speed things up.

## The problem

I thought I could create a function in my dashboard.component.ts which I could then iterate through in my html component and place this function outside of `ngOnInit`.  Here is what I have been playing with:

```
  get myData(){
      let result : myClass[];

    for(var item of Object.keys(this.myList)){

         let item1 = this.myList[item]
         for(var item2 of item1){
           if (item2.asset == "someString")
           {
             var myNewClass : historiantags;
             myNewClass.tagname = item2.tagname;
             myNewClass.value = item2.value;
             myNewClass.description = item2.description;
             myNewClass.units = item2.units;
             myNewClass.quality = item2.quality;
             myNewClass.timestamp = item2.timestamp;
             myNewClass.lowlimit = item2.lowlimit;
             myNewClass.highlimit = item2.highlimit;
             myNewClass.asset = item2.asset;
             result.push(myNewClass);
           }
         }
     }
     return result;
  }
```

I then tried to call this from my html component using:

```
<mat-card-content *ngFor="let com of myData">
```

This doesnt work as I get the error:

> item1 is not iterable

Is what I am trying to do possible or should I be thinking of it in a completely different way?

## *Update

I added the word `debugger` to the `myData` function and the line is never hit.  I also added `{{com | json}}` to the html and nothing is returned therefore I dont think `myData()` is getting called.

How do I make sure it is called?

Comment: What is the value of `item1` when logged?  Also, as a tip you can assign properties to a class a bit tighter using something like [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8bcmb1). Not as explicit but is less verbose.

Comment: @Phix I dont know.  I added some console.log("hello") lines to the myData() method just to see where it gets to when calling it but it doesnt display any in the console therefore I dont think it even gets called.

Comment: Hmm... can you recreate a small example on stackblitz?  Hard to tell from here.

Comment: Also i noticed you have mismatched variable names myList vs mylist

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using something like **JsonConvert** from https://www.npmjs.com/package/json2typescript that would allow you to easily convert your JSON in your **getcurrentvalues** method like so:

```
getcurrentvalues(): Observable<myClass[]> {
   return this.http.get('Your URL HERE')
     .pipe(
        map(response =>
          new JsonConvert().deserializeArray(response, myClass)
        )
   );
}
```

And then in your component your can do:

```
myList$: Observable<myClass[]>;

ngOnInit(){
  this.myList$ = this._myService.getcurrentvalues();
}
```

And in your html:

```
<mat-card-content *ngFor="let com of myList$ | async">
```